# Every point on the unit sphere has distance at most $d$ to some point in the set $S$, what is the lower bound for $|S|$?

Tags: spherical-geometry

Someone I know said "I wish no matter where I am, there is always a place near me so I can visit".

I started to wonder what is the minimum number of places required if he give me what he consider as "near".

I formalized it into a math problem:

> Every point on the unit sphere has distance at most $d$ to some point
>   in the set $S$, what is the lower bound for $|S|$?

I also wonder if there are any studies on the generalized version: replace unit sphere with any totally bounded spaces in the problem above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subset $S$ of the unit sphere has covering radius $r$ if each point of the sphere
lies at distance at most $r$ from some point in $S$. There is no known formula
which gives the minimum number of points required in a subset with covering radius $r$. Nonetheless it is an important problem, and you will find a table at
http://neilsloane.com/coverings/index.html (which reports on results of Hardin, Sloane and Smith).<sup>1</sup> Neil Sloane's web page is a natural place to start
if you want more information.

<sup>1</sup>Here is [Wayback Machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20190414084843/http://neilsloane.com/coverings/index.html) to prevent link rot.